# What will activating the web console (cockpit) do?

Tags: centos, cockpit

I just installed CentOS GNU/Linux (version 8 build 1905) on a machine; this wasn't my choice of distro - I'm a Debian man myself.

Anyway, when I SSH into this machine (as a non-root user), it tells me:

> Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

What will this web console have? On which port will it listen, and for whom? Can non-root users simply activate it when they want to? I'm somewhat baffled by this, as I'm not used to CentOS.

Comment: You create a lot of tags. Please add excerpts and wikis for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the fine manual at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_systems_using_the_rhel_8_web_console/getting-started-with-the-rhel-8-web-console_system-management-using-the-rhel-8-web-console

> What will this web console have?

The RHEL web console enables you a wide range of administration tasks, including:

```
Managing services
Managing user accounts
Managing and monitoring system services
Configuring network interfaces and firewall
Reviewing system logs
Managing virtual machines
Creating diagnostic reports
Setting kernel dump configuration
Configuring SELinux
Updating software
Managing system subscriptions
```

> On which port will it listen, and for whom?

Port 9090.  For all users.

> Can non-root users simply activate it when they want to?

Root privs needed to activate it.  Such privs not needed to log onto it, once it's activated.

So, give it a whirl, I'd suggest, see if it's useful for you.

Comment: @stever I see.sr By default, I'm guessing it is also willing to accept external connections?

Comment: Yes, it listens on port 9090 across all interfaces. Not just localhost.

Answer (score 3):

In brief generally we login to our account from CLI or GUI. After running following command

```
systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket
```

one can access their account from web browser.

Just need to type following for local run.

```
https://localhost:9090
```

Answer (score 1):

- Note that you are seeing a message that is unconditionally emitted from `/etc/motd.d/cockpit`.  Most likely this socket is already enabled.
- You do not have to be privileged user to check if enabled with `systemctl status cockpit.socket` (where you can also see the port).

```
[nhed@nhed-ds2vm1 ~]$ systemctl status cockpit.socket
● cockpit.socket - Cockpit Web Service Socket
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cockpit.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-02-11 10:24:48 EST; 15h ago
   Triggers: ● cockpit.service
       Docs: man:cockpit-ws(8)
     Listen: [::]:9090 (Stream)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2308)
     Memory: 904.0K
        CPU: 35ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cockpit.socket

Feb 11 10:24:48 nhed-ds2vm1 systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit Web Service Socket...
Feb 11 10:24:48 nhed-ds2vm1 systemd[1]: Listening on Cockpit Web Service Socket.
```

I suspect the main driver for this is for either "headless" servers or perhaps for some support functionality.

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]